# Как работает reduce и return в этой функции?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив arr = [1,2,3,4,5] и нужно написать функцию , которая возвращает массив его частичных сумм. Иначе говоря, вызов этой ф-ии должен возвращать новый массив из такого же числа элементов, в котором на каждой позиции должна быть сумма элементов arr до этой позиции включительно.

То еcть:

```js
arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
getSums( arr ) = [ 1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4, 1+2+3+4+5 ] = [ 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 ]
```

благодаря различным источникам я нашел решение:

```js
   
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
 
function getSums(el) { 
   let result = []; 
 
   el.reduce((sum, val, ind) => { 
      let sumEl = sum + val; 
      result[ind] = sumEl; 
      return sumEl; 
   }, 0); 
   return result; 
} 
 
console.log(getSums(arr));
```

Но у меня есть вопросы:

1. Зачем в качестве в качестве аргумента в getSums передавать el? Ведь получается, что под el подразумевается каждый элемент массива, но при этом внутри ф-ии применяется метод reduce, который и так предназначен для последовательной обработки каждого элемента массива... обычно же пишется arr.reduce, а тут в переводе на человеческий язык получается, что нужно выполнить какое-то действие над каждым элементов в каждом элементе.
2. Я не совсем понимаю строчку result[ind] = sumEl. Как я понял, этой строчка вносит результат суммы предыдущего и следующего элемента массива arr в массив result, верно? И это тоже самое, что push-ить сумму в новый массив? Просто опять же в переводе на человеческий язык это звучит как - КАЖДЫЙ индекс элемента массива result равен результату суммы элементов массива arr.
3. Почему код не работает без строчки return sumEl? Зачем его возвращать? Чтобы в reduce хранился результат суммы? Тот же вопрос про return result.

Comment: Вам откроется вся правда о данном скрипте, если прочитать про [reduce](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#reduce-reduceright) и [функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics). В фукнциях обратите внимание, что они умеют принимать параметры. А вот про el... Это скорее всего из раздела - [что бы враг не догадался](https://learn.javascript.ru/ninja-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. По этому поводу, вам правильно ответили в комментариях, это плохое именование переменных)
2. Да, верно, можно просто класть push(sumEl)
3. ' Чтобы в reduce хранился результат суммы?' - Да, callback-функция в функции reduce должна возвращать аккумулятор(сумму в этом случае sum), потому что на каждой итерации создается другой стек вызовов и reduce должен знать результаты предыдущих вызовов callback-функции.
   'Тот же вопрос про return result.' Потому что это результирующий массив, если его не возвращать, то функция вернет undefined.

reduce здесь используется для того что-бы не создавать два цикла.

Можно переписать это решение вот так:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 

const getSums = (numbers) => numbers
  .reduce((acc, currentNum) => {
     const prevNum = acc?.at(-1) ?? 0
     return [...acc, prevNum + currentNum]
   }, []);

console.log(getSums(arr));
```

метод 
[at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)
оператор 
[??](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)
оператор 
[?.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
синтаксис 
[...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: SwaD, спасибо))

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще один вариант уменьшения фукнции, без использования дополнительных переменных(и синтаксис чуть по проще)

```js
let arrToCalc = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

/**
 * @param {number[]} arr
 * @return {number[]}
 */
function getSums(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, val, ind) => {
    ind ? sum[ind] = sum[ind - 1] + val : sum[0] += val;
    return sum;
  }, [0]);
}

console.log(getSums(arrToCalc));
```